# use ecryptfs with sshfs

Tags: linux, sshfs, ecryptfs

I'm trying to use ecryptfs on top of sshfs to be able to create create and access an encrypted share on a new NAS box.

The following mount command works on both the NAS box and my local mancine:

```
mount -t ecryptfs /DATA/a_folder /DATA/another_folder
```

to create an encrypted folder.

I'm able to use

```
sshfs root@nashost:/DATA/some_folder /home/me/nas_box
```

on my local machine to mount a folder form my NAS box. However once I've mounted it, if I try and use ecryptfs like this

```
mount -t ecryptfs /home/me/nas_box /DATA/decrypted
```

then I get the following error

```
Error mounting eCryptfs: [-13] Permission denied
Check your system logs; visit <http://launchpad.net/ecryptfs>
```

I've looked in `/var/log/messages` on both machines, but there is nothing there. I've no idea if what I'm trying to do is possible or which logs to examine to help me.

Not sure if this matters but, the NAS box is Centos and my local machine is Ununtu.

Advise would be gratefully received.

---

just found the following in /var/log/syslog

```
mount.ecryptfs: could not resolve full path for source /home/me/nas_box [-13]
```

Answer (score -1):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2024094

> 

```
Hello all,

I am trying to mount SSHFS and then mount an ecryptfs encrypted directory inside of it. I have been able to do this with root. I have added the mounts to fstab with a user option so I can have non-root users mounting them. Using a non-root user I am able to mount SSHFS and I can mount an ecryptfs directory as long as the ecryptfs directory is not located within the SSHFS mount. When I try to mount the ecryptfs directory within an SSHFS directory using a non-root use I am presented with an error that there is a misconfiguration.

Anybody have any insight? I am stumped.

Thank You
```

Advanced reply
July 18th, 2012 #2
Seeked's Avatar
Seeked
Seeked is offline 5 Cups of Ubuntu

Re: SSHFS and ecryptfs

```
Use enfs instead of eCryptfs.

encfs works in the user space instead of the kernal space by default. 

Last edited by Seeked; July 23rd, 2012 at 08:45 PM.
```